# How to set HTTP as default scheme in API Platform Swagger UI?

Tags: php, symfony, swagger-ui, api-platform.com, symfony-4.3

I am building a web app using Symfony v4.3 and API Platform.

API Platform has OpenAPI documentation (Swagger UI) and every time I go to myweb_url/api/doc UI, scheme is set to HTTPS as default. I would like to configure it to HTTP as default scheme in api_platform.yaml config file.

Is this even the right place to do this and is this possible without decorating the whole UI?

Comment: What's the problem with using https ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The answer is nelmio_api_doc.yaml configuration

To achieve HTTP as default in api/doc, you need to put HTTP first in the scheme field in the **nelmio_api_doc.yaml** configuration:

```
nelmio_api_doc:

documentation:
    schemes: [http, https]
```